# celery: programmatically queue task to a specific queue?

Tags: python, celery

When I do `sometask.async_apply(args=['args1','args2'],  kwargs={'queue': 'dev'})` nothing ends up on the queue 'dev'. I'm wondering if I am missing a step somewhere? I have created the queue 'dev' already and it shows up under queues when I check the rabbitmq management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do something like that:

`sometask.apply_async(args = ['args1','args2'], queue = 'dev')`